# Fragments, Cards, ListViews and Images

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

It has been a long time since I did some Android and now I want to get back to it. I still try to grasp the concept of using Fragments properly and what would be the *proper way to do* what I need to.

To the point. I need to have a Main view that (for now) contains one card. This card will contain a TextView and a ListView with custom items(one image and two rows of text). How would I implement this?

Do I need to do a different fragment for the listView and another for the card? I know I need a custom Adapter for the list view but how do I go on putting everything together?

Any advice is welcomed, even in the most basic diagram form.

fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/accounts_card"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accounts_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:text="My Accounts"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/accounts_list"
                android:layout_below="@id/accounts_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my_listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/account_item">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b_logo"
        android:elevation="1dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/b_logo"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9959593922923"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_code"
            android:layout_below="@id/account_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="30-15-55"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to have different navigatable cards containing text and list views, I would recommend using a PageAdapter , in which each card can be  loaded to the adapter in the beginning of the Activity like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    mContext=collection.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
    //do things to initiate the card like loading a text by accessing the text through TextView tv=(TextView)view.findElementsById(R.id.accounts_title);
    return view;

}
```

And for the List in your card, create a New subclass of Base Adapter Class and instantiate the layout my_listitem.xml there and return the view for each item in  list , this can be done like this:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static List<?> list;
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            RelativeLayout layout = null;
            salahLayout=(RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.my_listitem, null);
            notifyDataSetChanged();// to notify the list has been changed
            return layout;

}

}
```

You may need to set the List in the CustomListAdapter Class using some setter method and then in the getView method you can create the view for each item in the list Item using the list.

To use the CustomListAdapter as the adapter for your list in the card in CustomAdapter class add this:

```
ListView list=(ListView)view.findElementById(R.id.accounts_list);
list.setAdapter(mCustomListAdapter);//set the object of the customlistadapter class
```

Fragments are used for changing part of Main UI .Refer the Below link:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: thanks, that's pretty informative. It will take me some time to go through all these and I will get back to you